# SDL2 / SDL Image strange PNG behavior with RGB values

Tags: c++, png, sdl, sdl-image

I found an interesting thing that I'm not able to debug but I'd like to solve because it's crucial for the development of a small tool I need.

Basically all reduces to the fact that I load into an `SDL_Surface` a PNG loaded with `IMG_Load("filename.png")`. The skeleton of the code is

```
surface = IMG_Load("filename.png");
```

Then this tool should copy this surface pixel by pixel to another by applying a color map (which is just an `unordered_map<u32,u32>`). This basically works, but many pixel have a slight change in their RGB values so this substitution fails.

For example, while a pixel 255,255,255 is correctly stored as 0xFFFFFFFF in the surface, another pixel, let's say 81,60,48 becomes 82,62,51. I thought about gamma correction but the image itself is not drawn since the color switch is applied before two surfaces, and the latter gets drawn to a texture just afterwards.

Any clues? I'm not interested in finding another solution to my problem since I require to be able to do precise pixel color switching with a fixed map, I'd just like to understand why this is happening (since PNG should just contain exact values, being lossless) and solve it.

Comment: Does your monitor have some kind of color calibration applied to it?

Comment: @Mark Ransom: No, I'm running on OSX and it has its default calibration. Indeed I tried to obtain the default gamma ramp through `SDL_GetWindowGammaRamp` but the values seemed just linear. I like to emphasize the fact that I'm working on raw data, displaying it is just a later stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the cause and fixed it. The problem resides in how the PNG is loaded through the OS X frameworks. According to [this](https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=31258) thread, this is related to the [embedded calibration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB) which is somehow taked into account while loading the image. The proposed [fix](https://gist.github.com/albertz/1551404) is the following:

```
CGFloat whitePoint[3] = { 1, 1, 1 };
CGFloat blackPoint[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
CGFloat gamma[3] = { 2.2, 2.2, 2.2 };
CGFloat matrix[9] = {
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1
};
CGColorSpaceRef color_space =
    CGColorSpaceCreateCalibratedRGB(
                                whitePoint, blackPoint, gamma, matrix
                                );
```

By patching `ImageIO.m` of `SDL_Image` and rebuilding it from sources the problem resolved itself. I wonder why it hasn't been included in SDL_Image (or rather, just a version with custom values).